# Inclusive optional CLI arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a single python script that will perform differently depending on if certain optional arguments are provided.

I currently have 3 cases:

1. CLI options only
2. Config file only
3. Config file and data file

The config and data files are also privided via cli args.

Here is what I want to improve:

```
    if args.name is not None and\
   (args.delay is None or
    args.hostid is None or
    args.interfaceid is None or
    args.key_ is None or
    args.type is None
   ):
```

Of course this doesn't cover any case where args.name is not given, but any other in the list *is* given.

I have found documentation on mutually exclusive args, but nothing for this case. Maybe I just missed it somehow.

Comment: did you look at argparse? [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html#)

Comment: @SalmaanP Yes, I am using argparse. I experimented with putting these in a group and that's nice for the --help, but couldn't get anywhere with making sure that they were required only if one of the others in the group were given or not required if the user is intending to use a different method listed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
config_file = args.name
cli_options_present = any(getattr(args, a) is None
                          for a in 'delay hostid interfaceid key_ type'.split())
if not bool(config_file) ^ cli_options_present:
    raise ValueError('Must specify either CLI options or config file, but not both.')

if config_file:
    if args.data_file:
        pass  # fill in
    else:
        pass  # fill in
else:
    pass  # fill in
```

`^` is the xor (exclusive or) operation.

Comment: I going to try this soon. Looks very interesting.